# Method in "Release" doesnt work correctly

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, sfml, release

I'm new in C++, so i've got a problem. In "Debug" mode i get this picture, which is correct: all of the walls are transparent

[image: All colourful walls are transparent as it should be]

But in "Release" mode I get this:

[image: Some walls are transparent and some of them are not, which is not correct]

I'm sure that i messed up with my wall class and creating object:

```
std::vector<Wall> glassWalls = {
    Wall(Vec2(2.0f, 1.0f), Vec2(2.0f, 2.0f),true,255, 0, 0,  0.5f),
    Wall(Vec2(2.0f, 2.0f), Vec2(3.0f, 1.0f),true, 255, 0, 0, 0.5f),
    Wall(Vec2(3.0f, 1.0f), Vec2(2.0f, 1.0f), true, 255, 0, 0, 0.5f),
    Wall(Vec2(1.0f, 3.0f), Vec2(3.0f, 7.0f), true, 0, 255, 0, 0.5f),
    Wall(Vec2(3.0f, 7.0f), Vec2(3.0f, 4.0f), true, 0, 255, 0, 0.5f),
    Wall(Vec2(3.0f, 4.0f), Vec2(1.0f, 3.0f), true, 0, 255, 0, 0.5f),
    Wall(Vec2(5.0f, 7.0f), Vec2(6.0f, 7.0f), true, 255, 255, 0, 0.5f),
    Wall(Vec2(6.0f, 7.0f), Vec2(6.0f, 6.0f), true, 255, 255, 0, 0.5f),
    Wall(Vec2(6.0f, 6.0f), Vec2(5.0f, 7.0f), true, 255, 255, 0, 0.5f),
    Wall(Vec2(5.0f, 1.0f), Vec2(5.0f, 4.0f), true, 255, 0, 255, 0.5f),
    Wall(Vec2(5.0f, 4.0f), Vec2(7.0f, 5.0f), true, 255, 0, 255, 0.5f),
    Wall(Vec2(7.0f, 5.0f), Vec2(5.0f, 1.0f), true, 255, 0, 255, 0.5f)
};
```

And here is my method that should return color by dist

```
int red = std::min((int)(std::max((-colorR / WALL_VISIBILITY * dist + colorR + emmision * 255.0f), 0.0f)), colorR);
    int green = std::min((int)(std::max((-colorG / WALL_VISIBILITY * dist + colorG + emmision * 255.0f), 0.0f)), colorG);
    int blue = std::min((int)(std::max((-colorB / WALL_VISIBILITY * dist + colorB + emmision * 255.0f), 0.0f)), colorB);
    if (isGlass) {
        sf::Color newCol(red, green, blue, std::max(std::min((int)(transparency * 255), 255), 0));
        return newCol;
    }
    else {
        float k = std::max(std::min(transparency, 1.0f), 0.0f);
        return sf::Color((int)(red * k), (int)(green * k), (int)(blue * k));
    }
```

Comment: You have lots of divisions and multiplications. Are you sure there won't be any kind of under/overflow situations? Especially when converting to `int`?

Comment: By the way, in C++ you shouldn't really use C-style casting for conversions. Use the C++ primitives like `static_cast` etc (unless the implicit conversions rules already does the right thing). Using C-style casting is almost always a sign that you're doing something wrong that will lead to *undefined behavior* (which is probably what happens if the code behaves differently when doing an optimized release build).

Comment: Why not use the debugger to see the values you're using?  Or simply print out the intermediate values and see if they're the same value between debug and release?

Comment: Possibly the most common cause of this discrepancy is leaving variables uninitialized.

Answer (score 0):

[molbdnilo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/404970/molbdnilo) was right, i messed up with my constructor. Class had field "isGlass" and constructor has "isGlass" too.

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.